# Why Azure Data Factory DataFlow is only processing one line per file?

Tags: azure, data-science, azure-data-factory

I have configured a Dataflow in Azure Data Factory to process multiple files. The data in the files is in JSON format and contains multiple lines of content(array of objects). However, when the pipeline finishes running, the processed files only contain a single line of data instead of the expected entire data.I am processing the files to remove one of the Attributes highlighted below schema.
**Pipeline**
[image]

**The schema of input source file**

[image]

**and my Dataflow looks like this**
[image]

Following are the steps that I am performing

1. Take a derived column transformation and convert the attributes object to string using expression toString(attributes)
2. Then parse the String attributes as below as (session as string,     orgToken as string, partnerToken as string) and leave the userID out of it.
3. Then in select transformation delete the attributes object and rename the parsed object as attributes that only contains session,orgToken, partnerToken removing userID out of it.

**Output**: The output of the pipeline is expected but it only processes one line per file and not the whole content of the file means 6 files processed contains one line per file rather than whole data. I tried single document, array of objects, documents per line but no success as shown below

```
{"date":"2023-07-06\t15:33:36.464","level":"INFO","msg":"Init","resource":{"class":"NuCaSessionManager","function":"Init","line":167,"module":"NuCa","pid":24848,"thread":"[25824]"},"spanId":"asfffwfe","traceId":"acas","attributes":{}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have nested array and maybe it doesn't have proper Json format of array of document.  so you need to first convert it into array of objects.
**Array of Json format should be as below:**

```json
[
{.....},
{.....}
]
```

**You can use copy activity to transform it:**

- In your pipeline take copy activity under foreach activity and pass the file as source and use same file as sink and in sink set `file pattern` as **Array of Object**.
  [image]
- After this use this file in your dataflow.